# Perl File Handling question?

Tags: perl, file, scripting

I have names of all files in `output.txt` but I do not have `folderpath` in `output.txt` file. For Example, if `filename = test.txt` and its `folderpath=/usr/local/bin` than in `output.txt` file, I only have `filename as test.txt`

`output.txt` files has many entries for `filename`, what I am trying to do is:

1. Move all files present `output.txt` to some another folder say '/usr/local/test/data/', so my question is how can I do that using `Perl Script` ?
2. Delete all the files which are present in `output.txt` file from the actual location, using their `folderpath`, so for example, script should first move `test.txt` to some other folder location, say, `/usr/local/test/data/test.txt` and delete test.txt from its actual location using folderpath information, i.e., script should delete `/usr/local/bin/test.txt`

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**Updates:**
Below scripts reads the output.txt file and gets size of each file and total size of all the files present in the output.txt

```
my $folderpath = 'the_path';
open my $IN, '<', 'path/to/infile';
my $total;
while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    my $size = -s "$folderpath/$_";
    print "$_ => $size\n";
    $total += $size;
}
print "Total => $total\n";
```

Courtesy: [RickF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447771/rickf) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746552/file-manipulation-scripting-question/3753986#3753986)

**Output.txt**

```
2304_2328_Test Data November 19 2003 - Test Tele.xls
2344_2341_Data Dummy Test 12-17.doc
2343_2342_Dummy Test Test 12-17.doc
```

My output.txt file also have some files whose name contain special characters, for example, 
63551_106640_63551 IBM`&#253`;Software Delivery&Fulfillment(Div-61) Data IPS 08-20-2010 v3.xlsm

If you see above the file has encoded value of `&#253` but my filename has actual special character symbol for that and so will copy or move take my this file also into account and move the files.

Comment: Can you show a few lines of your `output.txt` file, as well as the contents of your script so far (if you've started writing it yet)?

Comment: If you want to refer to the file in unix, do you use "?" in the filename, or the special char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion would be to use perl's [`rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) function.  You can use this to *move* files like so:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my $folderpath = '/some/where/';   # is it really "/usr/local/bin"? be careful now!!
my $tofolder   = '/usr/local/test/data';  # must have permissions to use this and $folderpath

my @files = ('test.txt', 'someotherfile.txt');

for my $file (@files) {
    rename "$folderpath/$file", "$tofolder/$file"
        or warn "Couldn't move $file";
}
```

Comment: `File::Copy` has a `move` function that may be safer.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Can you give an example.

Comment: hwo to handle files with special characters in their name ? Will copy take into account special characters file ?

Comment: This will only work when moving files along the same disk, won't it?

Comment: Yes `File::Copy` is the more universal way to go.  My `suggestion` was *teach someone to fish* answer hence including link to perldoc (http://perldoc.perl.org) and the query over perms etc.  The (original) question was described as Unix only solution.. so I was hoping OP would see the `rename` footnote: *For a platform independent move function look at the `File::Copy` module.*